# Output on Running PHP from Command Line

Tags: ubuntu, php

When running PHP on CLI, with same script concurrently on Ubuntu Linux, I have this:

```
[1]   Done                    php /var/www/html/deletebadsubjtermsnew.php 150 2 > /var/www/html/deletebadsubjtermsnew8Feb17-R3-2.log.txt
[2]   Done                    php /var/www/html/deletebadsubjtermsnew.php 150 3 > /var/www/html/deletebadsubjtermsnew8Feb17-R3-3.log.txt
[3]   Done                    php /var/www/html/deletebadsubjtermsnew.php 150 4 > /var/www/html/deletebadsubjtermsnew8Feb17-R3-4.log.txt
[4]   Done                    php /var/www/html/deletebadsubjtermsnew.php 150 5 > /var/www/html/deletebadsubjtermsnew8Feb17-R3-5.log.txt
[5]-  Done                    php /var/www/html/deletebadsubjtermsnew.php 150 6 > /var/www/html/deletebadsubjtermsnew8Feb17-R3-6.log.txt
[6]+  Done                    php /var/www/html/deletebadsubjtermsnew.php 150 7 > /var/www/html/deletebadsubjtermsnew8Feb17-R3-7.log.txt
```

WHat is the - and + for next to [5] and [6]?

Answer (score 0):

**From man bash:**

> In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command), the current job is always flagged with a +, and the previous job with a -.

The `+` job will come to the foreground with `fg`